# Adding view above origin of UIScrollView iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to add UIViews above its origin.

For example

Suppose i have added subview A at origin (x= 0 , y = 0);
now i want to add another subview B above this subview so i tried

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -500, 200, 500)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[scrollView addSubview:view];

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 500)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, scrollView.frame.size.height+500)];
```

I want to add many views like this while scrolling to top i.e. when scrollview reaches at top add another view above current view and scrolling should be without any lacking.

But with above code it does now show above added views.

Comment: There is some [sample code by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for infinite scrolling. Although it's scrolling horizontally it might give you an idea or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're looking at this the wrong way. If you have a scroll view with a total content size of lets say 1000, and you set the content offset to 500, then if you want to add a view that is 500 above the visible top of the scroll view, you should set that views origin to 0. Although you want this view to appear 500 pts above the currently visible portion of the scroll view, you have to create the coordinates in the coordinate space of the scroll view, which start at 0,0 left to right, top to bottom. Try this instead:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 500)];
```

EDIT:

Since you want to move this view above an existing subview, you have to make adjustments to the frames of both objects. The new view and still be set up as listed above, but you would need to call `setFrame:` on the existing view, and set its y origin to a value measuring at least the height of the view that you've added above it.

Comment: This is add view on top of previous view A. because View A also has y=0 and x= 0. how would i slip view A below view B(newly added) so that view A's origin becomes (x= 0, y = 500).

Comment: @mann See my edit. You have to change the frame of the existing sub view.

Comment: I am 100% sure this wont be correct approach. So if there are 10,000 views and you are adding new one then you have to shift 10,000 first? Sorry but it sounds bit awkward

Comment: @mann Well what you're doing is a fundamentally wrong approach if you're planning on using anywhere near 10,000 views.

Comment: I am not sure i am doing something unusual. I think same functionality is used in FB or Twitter? So if you have new feeds it automatically appears above your current visible rect.

Comment: I have already achieved this with UITableView but i want to do it with ScrollVidw

Comment: @mann I'm not sure what to tell you, this is what UITableView was designed to do. If you try to remake this functionality with a scroll view, you'll run into all kinds of problems, mainly with memory.

Comment: i want to show http://postimg.org/image/e5ok5hybl/ sort of events on top of tableview. So if i use UITableview and use each cell = each day then if Event popup is for 2 contuous days then as cell refresh it wont draw it properly. Thats why i need scrollview

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the total content size up-front (as `UITableView` does by calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) and place your subviews within the scroll view's bounds. So in this case, view A would be at (0, 500) and view B would be at (0, 0). You can add and remove views dynamically as scrolling happens, but setting the content size up-front is going to make things a lot easier.

Comment: Calculating content size is easy before adding subview but how View A will slip down y =500?. I just tried what you said

Comment: [self configureView];
    UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 500)]; //Already there
    viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:viewA];
    
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, scrollView.frame.size.height+500)]; // changing content size
    
    UIView *viewB = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 500)]; //NEW VIEW
    viewB.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:viewB];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 500)];

Comment: I don't exactly understand your comment. You may be confused about how scroll views work. When you scroll, it is the scroll view's bounds that change. The placement of views within the bounds remain fixed. So you'd place view A at (0, 500) and you don't need to move it. To have view A appear at the top of the screen, you set the scroll view's content offset to (0, 500).

Comment: Sure your above comment is 100% true. So A (0,500). B (0,0). Right. i can set contentOffset to (0,500). Now i want to add another view C above B. so what would be its origin (0,0)? but B already has (0,0) as you said views inside scrollView remain fixed.

Comment: I'm proposing that you lay out ALL views up front. This is how both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` work.